# Javascript input listener

Tags: javascript, input, addeventlistener

I have a table of products ordered by the value of the last column of each row. I want that when I click on an input, the corresponding checkbox change directly to selected. In this way, when I click on the Save button, only the selected products will be managed to update in the database.

The original code has too many things that are not related to the question, so I have reduced it to this:

```
var c = 10;
var count = 1;
pageList.forEach(element => {
    document.getElementById("tabla_variantes").innerHTML+=`
        <tr style="background: white;">
            <th class="check_col" scope="row" style="padding: 0px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                <input type="checkbox" value="${element.numero}" id="row${count}" name="row-check-pro">
            </th>
            <td> //image </td>
            <td> //product number </td>
            <td> //product name </td>
            <td> //product reference </td>
            <td> //product price </td>
            <td> //product stock </td>
            <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 8px 18px;">
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-end" id="posicion${element.numero}" value="${c}">
            </td>
        </tr>
    `;
    document.getElementById(`posicion${element.numero}`).addEventListener('input', (evt) => {
        console.log('run'); // Do something
        document.getElementById("row"+count).checked = true;
    });
    ++count;
    c += 10;
    if (c > list.length*10) c = 10;
});
```

As you can see I have tried to add a listener to each input, but nothing is showing on the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You REALLY should delegate

Also I suggest using map instead of concatenating to the DOM.

This is a drop in replace

```js
const container = document.getElementById("tabla_variantes");
const pageList = [{numero:1},{numero:2},{numero:3}];

container.addEventListener('input', (evt) => {
  const tgt = evt.target; 
  if (tgt.name==="row-check-pro") {
    if (!tgt.checked) tgt.closest("tr").querySelector(".text-end").value="";
  }  
  if (tgt.classList.contains("text-end")) {
    tgt.closest("tr").querySelector("[name=row-check-pro]").checked = tgt.value.trim() != ""; 
  }  
});


var c = 10;
var count = 1;
container.innerHTML+= pageList.map(element => {
  const str = `<tr style="background: white;">
            <th class="check_col" scope="row" style="padding: 0px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                <input type="checkbox" value="${element.numero}" id="row${count}" name="row-check-pro">
            </th>
            <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 8px 18px;">
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-end" id="posicion${element.numero}" value="${c}">
            </td>
        </tr>
    `;
    ++count;
    c += 10;
    if (c > pageList.length*10) c = 10;
    return str;
}).join("");
```

```html
<table id="tabla_variantes">
</table>
```

Comment: You don't **need** to, but you probably **should**. :-)

Comment: I'm thinking about rendering the html with `insertAdjacentHTML` would be a better option.

Comment: @FaridShokri - Certainly in some cases. Here the OP seems to want to completely replace the contents of the target element, so building up one string and passing just one complete string to the browser to parse and build the entire structure in one go probably makes more sense.

Comment: I don't understand really good how to delegate, so I will try what T.J. Crowder says.

Comment: @EmiliBellotPulido this IS delegation: `container.addEventListener('input', (evt) => { const tgt = evt.target; tgt.closest("tr").querySelector("[name=row-check-pro]").checked = true;});` -  I delegate the click from the container, so any element in the container can detect the input and it will be processed as above. You can add to this function by testing the tgt.tagName or classList

Comment: But this checks all checkboxes or just the one in the same row?

Comment: JUST the one in the same row as what received input

Comment: Okey, I will try. Thanks

Comment: That is what `tgt.closest("tr")` does - access the closest tr of the target input field and find the checkbox from there

Comment: @EmiliBellotPulido - Where I said you should consider "event delegation and DOM traversal," the event delegation here is handling the click on `container`, and the DOM traversal is the `tgt.closest("tr").querySelector(...)` part. :-)

Comment: I have tried but it's difficult for me to adapt all code I have to this delegate. Can somebody make a private chat with me to find a solution?

Comment: @EmiliBellotPulido No. But see the update. It is a drop in replacement of your code. I changed the checked a little to only check if the value was not empty

Comment: Okey, thanks. No I am getting this error: pageDetails.js:434 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': 'name=row-check-pro' is not a valid selector.

Comment: You need `"[name=row-check-pro]"` - sorry

Comment: Nice, but now, when the check is checked and I click on it, the check doesn't unchecked.

Comment: Haha, ok. we have to narrow it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231606/discussion-between-emili-bellot-pulido-and-mplungjan).

Comment: I made an update. If you uncheck, the textfield is cleared, if you change the textfield, the checkbox is checked if the field has value

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you're using `+=` with `innerHTML`. That's never a good idea. When you do `x.innerHTML += str`, the browser has to work through all of the elements within the `x` element, build an HTML string, return that string to the JavaScript code, then accept the updated string from the JavaScript code, **tear down** all the previous child elements of `x`, and replace them with **new** child elements created by parsing the new string. All state for those elements is lost, including any event handlers they have on them.

The minimal change is to:

1. Build up all the HTML in a string variable
2. Assign it to `innerHTML`
3. Find the elements and add event handlers to them

But you should consider using event delegation and DOM traversal rather than handlers on each individual element. More about event delegation in [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688293/157247), but the short version is you handle the event on a common ancestor element, then use `event.target` to determine what descendant was targeted by the event.